# Hibernate SQL error

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I try to get this example project running: 
https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples

Everytime a sql-query is placed it results in a 404 Error. 
For example I can load the main page without problems. But if I put

```
User test = userRepository.findByEmail("test")
```

somewhere in the code i get the 404 Error again. Also everytime I try to do something like login -> 404. 
From the logs i see the sql query which works fine if I copy it into phpmyadmin. Except for this logging I se nothing.

If I place a logging before and after the query I only see the first one. I guess the query somehow crashes and produces a 404.

I know 404 means not found but this does not make any sense.

What can I do? Is there a way to turn up more loggings?

I use Glassfish with the source provided from github.

Comment: Can you please post implementation of UserRepository. What I see on the github is only interface

Comment: Yeah it is just the interface. It is being autowired

Comment: but you need the implementation, don't you?

Comment: Nope. The implementation comes from the framework